# Saving checked box value as 0 or 1 in the database from Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have a few columns in the database which I have configured as `TINYINT`. I have the same number of check boxes as well on the front end.

Here's my HTML,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="project">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well well-small">
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    You can create a new Project by filling this simple form.
                </p>

                <p style="text-align: center"> Project Name should be minimum 10 characters & There's no limit on
                    Project Description.
                </p>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectname">Project Name: </label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="projectname" id="projectname" required
                               title="Project Name is Required!" pattern="[A-z ]{10,}"
                               placeholder="Enter Project Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectdesc">Project Description:</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea rows="3" id="projectdesc" name="projectdesc" placeholder="Enter Project Desc"
                                  required="Description Required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Roles:</label>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" id="script" value="false"> Script
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" id="design" value="false"> Design
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" id="writer" value="false"> Writer
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" id="storyboard" value="false"> Storyboard
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" id="workbook" value="false"> Workbook
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn"
                        {{action 'createNew'}}>Add Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And here's what I am doing,

```
           function(event) {
            $(":text, input[type='checkbox'], textarea").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === "") {
                    alert("Empty Fields!");
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    App.Project.createNew();
                    alert("Project Created");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
```

And the Ajax POST,

```
            dataString = {
            'projectname' : $("#projectname").val(),
            'projectdesc' : $("#projectdesc").val(),
            'script' : $('input.roles[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).val()
        };
        console.log('check');
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://ankur.local/users/createNewProject",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                alert('');
            }
        });
        return false;
```

You can see from my code that I am trying to grab the **checked** value of the textbox which I want to store in the database as 0 or 1 or True or False perhaps? Moreover I want to have a condition that out of the given checkboxes, at least one should be checked.

```
'script' : $('input.roles[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).val()
```

How can I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

Condition for checking at least one checkbox is checked

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0)
{
  //do your work
}else
{
 alert("Please check any checkbox");
return false;
}
```

do this check prior to posting your data.

Get the value for saving in database

```
  //will give the value attribute of selected checkbox
    // true/false in this case
    var value = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();

//for getting value in 1 or 0 from the above variable.
 var value1 = value ? 1 : 0;
```

For saving all check box values.

```
var all_values= "";
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
var value = $(this).is(":checked") ;

all_values = all_values + "~" + value ;
});
```

send the value of all_values  to your code, use split to get all the values.

Comment: How would I insert the individual checkbox values into database?

Comment: You mean inserting check state of all check box or only one at a time ?

Comment: I have individual fields in the database for each checkbox, so each field would have a value of either 0 or 1.